# set partition bootable with gdisk GPT

Tags: partition, system-installation, hard-disk, ext3, gpt

Using [GPT](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/), how do I set this disk:

```
sda1    ext3    FUJITSUMHV2080B
```

so that the partition is bootable?  Or, do I need to reformat using the [install disk](http://www.android-x86.org/)?

Comment: A GPT partition hasn't bootable flag at all, this function can be emulated with a loader specific technique. Linux also doesn't use it directly, preferring to install LILO/GRUB/etc. onto master boot place. But, with 80GB drive, you don't need GPT until OS requires it.

Comment: Interesting.  Probably, that answers the question.  What should happen during the prompt for GRUB?

Comment: No need for "bootable flag". One of my disks is GPT with 26  partitions : No problem booting all the installed 'Linux OS´s' from grub. ( Currently 10 different OS, Debian´s, Ubuntu´s, Slackware, PCLinuxOS.)  -